# LDAP authentication with Apache Nifi not working

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, apache-nifi

I have been working on this problem for quite some time and I would like answers and suggestions from you guys on the issue I am facing. I am trying to get my Nifi standalone instance on my VM, which is in my company's network, authenticated using the ldap-provider in *login-identity-providers.xml*. I input all the required values except for the truststores and keystores because the company has an LDAP and not LDAPS . So, I figured I wouldn't need those certificates. I have set the initial admin identity in the *authorizers.xml* too. And, of course, set the https port and host(0.0.0.0). But, when I try to run and call the server from the browser using the url, the *Site can't be reached* , **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** pops up. Basically, can't reach the server. I have checked the DN, LDAP url and other properties to be correct and working when I queried through *ldapsearch*.

So, is it because I don't specify the truststore and keystore in the configuration? If so, do i need to manually create these certs for each client that wish to access Nifi. I thought the LDAP certificate would be enough for a person to authenticate to Nifi. Please advise me on how to go about getting the CA for truststore, server and client certificates for the employees to use Nifi through LDAP.

My ldap-provider looks like this(scrubbed) :

```
<provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>

    <property name="Manager DN">cn=user-name,ou=Accounts,dc=domain,dc=company-name,dc=com</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">My-account-password</property>

    <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Protocol">TLS</property>
    <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

    <property name="Referral Strategy">IGNORE</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

    <property name="Url">the-ldap-url-of-company</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">cn=Users,ou=Accounts,dc=corp,dc=company-name,dc=com</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">sAMAccountName={0}</property>

    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
</provider>
```

Nifi version - 1.0.0
Running in a Ubuntu Trusty VM.

Comment: have you been able to connect nifi using LDAP user and password without generating keystore and truststore etc..as i want simple user/password authentication and getting same error..

Comment: Follow the answer and it's associated comments thread. You would need to create a keystore and truststore. Make use of the nifi-toolkit to generate those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using LDAP authentication you should reach a login page for NiFi where you supply the username and password to authenticate against LDAP. Since you are not even reaching that page, something else is wrong before it is even getting to the LDAP part.

Some things to check...

In NiFi properties the active identity provider should be set with the following property:

```
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
```

When you are using any kind of authentication NiFi must be configured to use https which requires providing the following configuration:

```
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=

nifi.security.keystore=
nifi.security.keystoreType=
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=
nifi.security.truststoreType=
nifi.security.trustStorePassword=
```

The hostname that you set in nifi.web.https.host should also line up with the hostname of the certificate being used for the nifi.security.keystore. I have a feeling that setting the https host to 0.0.0.0 is not what you want, but I'm not totally sure what that does.

Once you get the https configuration correct, then you should reach the login page when going to https://yourhost:post/nifi and after that is where your LDAP configuration will come into play.

Comment: So if I need to set the keystore and truststore, do I create my own or since I am using LDAP config of my company, would I need to get my company's CA certificates or something of that sort? If i create my own truststore and keystore certificate, should it's DN match with my DN from the LDAP? I am kinda confused in that aspect.

Comment: This keystore and truststore is not related to LDAP in anyway, its so that when your browser makes an https connection to NiFi, the communication will be encrypted and NiFi will be identified. The DN would typically be the hostname of the NiFi host. The NiFi community recently released a toolkit to help generate certs, take a look at the documentation here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#tls-generation-toolkit  It is available to download on the main downloads page.

Comment: Sorry for asking another question on this because I am pretty new to this. So, let's suppose I generate certs and set the truststore and keystore in `nifi.properties`. Now, if other users want to access the Nifi instance, do I need to get a client certificate created for them too? Or, does LDAP take care of that if i just set the keystore and truststore in the host. Thanks

Comment: If you have the LDAP identity provider configured they will get sent to a login page for LDAP authentication, assuming they do not have a client cert in their browser. If they have a client cert in their browser, usually the browser prompts asking if you want to use that cert, and if you say yes it will bypass the LDAP login page.

Comment: I made use of the nifi-toolkit and got ldap working. Thanks. I was able to login into nifi with the ldap username password. But, then page says not enough permissions to access anything Couldn't even see the NIfi flow page. So, this means LDAP is working but I guess the initial admin DN is not getting recognized properly. I used that DN to search my records in ldapsearch and it worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working. Someone mentioned on the mailing list that when using LDAP they had to make the Initial Admin DN lowercase in authorizers.xml, even though they thought it wasn't lower case in LDAP, but I haven't been able to test this myself. If make changes to the value of the initial admin you will want to delete users.xml and authorizations.xml before restarting so that it regenerates them from scratch.

Comment: The lower case didn't seem to work. But, I went into the nifi-suer.log and saw that the DN is getting resolved differently once authenticated by the login page. So, I copied that into the _initial.admin.indentity_ in the authorizers.xml file and it **worked**. Thanks a bunch. I am marking yours as the answer with the comments.

Comment: I don't understand when you say that `NiFi must be configured to use https`. My NiFi service is behind a proxy that is handling the encryption which means that my NiFi service is running on just HTTP. Does this mean that I will not be able to use LDAP because I have to add truststores and such that I do not have?

Comment: @BryanBende, just wondering if you hang out on the Slack Workspace or the email lists.  Been trying to setup LDAP authentication but getting an error that I really don't understand.  I followed an article on the [Mint Ops Blog](https://mintopsblog.com/2017/11/01/apache-nifi-configuration/) to setup LDAP but it is not working. Will delete this comment in a few days.

Comment: @Squashman I hang out on both :) I think I just responded to your email.